# How to get from Split to Supetar by ferry?

Tags: ferries, croatia, split

Someone told me that Jadrolinija is operating ferries in Croatia. However, their [site](http://www.jadrolinija.hr/) is somehow confusing.

Is there any other site with ferry timetables, or specifically, timetables of the Split - Supetar ferry?

Comment: What exactly do you find confusing? I managed to find rather quickly (3 or 4 clicks) the following page, which has timetables: http://www.jadrolinija.hr/default.aspx?dpid=1522

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am from Croatia and I find their site confusing as well.

Maybe [this link](http://www.voznired.net/Timetable/Split/Supetar%20%28Brac%29) can help you.

IMHO, on this link you have very clear timetable for selected date if that is what you want to find

Comment: This link is not working for me. Could you please write the times the ferry departs from Split since, as you can see, websites misbehave sometimes. Thank you.

Comment: my mistake, this link i pasted correct link above

Answer (score 4):

On [this page](http://www.jadrolinija.hr/default.aspx?dpid=1304), after selecting the *English* language, you can easily find all the schedule between Split and Supetar (and other cities).

As I've understood, these ferries are quite easy to use - they are frequent (near once in *2 hours*) and fast (near *50 minutes* to go).